# Re-execute fc command from history

Tags: bash, command-history

Sometimes I am using the `fc` builtin in `bash` (3.2 if that matters), to recall commands from the history. This also offers the possibility to edit, before execution.

For example, by typing

```
fc 23 27
```

I can re-execute command 23 till 27. But now I want to execute this specific `fc 23 27` command again. How should I do that? It looks as if the executed `fc` is not stored in the command history, although the newly executed lines are.

Comment: Heard first time this command `fc`. Thanks for enlightening :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your .bashrc :

```
fc() {
    command fc "$@"
    history -s fc $@
}
```

Comment: Nice, this works. Would be neat if there was a built-in solution instead of a function. I'll award you the bounty in case of no better answers.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your `fc 23 27` to history and reinvoke it later:

```
knoedel@section60:~> bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

knoedel@section60:~> history -s "fc 4074 4076"
knoedel@section60:~> history | tail -n 2
 4090  15/12/2013 11:31:23 > fc 4074 4076
 4091  15/12/2013 11:31:25 > history | tail
knoedel@section60:~> fc -s 4090
```

so `fc -s 4090` actually runs `fc 4074 4076` but only in this session. If you  logout and login again the history command numbers change. At least as I tested it. (probably when BASH_HISTSIZE is reached)

To avoid running the wrong commands I suggest saving your commands from history to a shell script with `fc -n -l id id > ~/bin/something.sh`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only, I do not understand how it is different from the one by @Baronsed?

Comment: You asked for a solution with built-in tools - that is my suggestion. I did not really understand why you asked for such a solution in the first place. 
Baronsed already answered your question and you can use the same solution without that bash script.I just added a bit text to explain it, ok?

Comment: I was hoping for a solution like: `fc --keepinhistory 22 34` or `export HISTNOTIGNORE=fc`. But, apparently that does not exist.

Comment: if you want to use old commands for ever disable bash history. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663078/disable-history-in-linux
otherwise new commands get added to history (except fc which is no new command but running old ones again - running the last command again is the same .. it does not get added to history)
hth

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to say, but I do not want to disable history. I only want the `fc` command that I type to be added to history.

Comment: IMHO "fc" does get added to history because it's not a new command (like running the last command again and again). another point is this: if "fc" is always added to history you can accidently run an endless loop of commands if fc runs old commands that involve fc.
you still can add fc to history with "history -s" but this doesn't work for ever as command numbering in bash history change some day. hth

Comment: That makes sense. It is probably a feature :)

Comment: And I think that adding to history is dependent on the `HISTCONTROL` environment variable! In my case, it's set to `ignoreboth`, this means that both duplicate lines and those starting with a (white)space will be left out and never added to history. However, what if `HISTCONTROL` gets set to *another* value? I guess there will be a way to add the dupes too (if you keenly insist on it ;))