# Copy command from history to bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, keyboard, command-history

Sometimes I'd like to get some command from `history` output, copy it to a bash prompt, make some changes and run it. Is there a way to copy a command from `history` output to a bash prompt without involving the mouse? For example, it would be some script that I can bind a shortcut to.

Maybe I do not understand `fc` enough, but it looks like I cannot select folders or files via `fc` (like <kbd>Tab</kbd> for usual command prompt)

Comment: you should take a look here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104394/53092

Comment: fc 'command begins… '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a `tmux` way.
Enter command number (like `!1234`) and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. After that command with number `1234` will be printed in terminal prompt and this command is editable as usual.

```
copy_line_from_history_to_prompt () {
  READLINE_LINE=$( history -p "$READLINE_LINE" ) ;
}
bind -x '"eX": copy_line_from_history_to_prompt' # Alt+Shift+X
```

Comment: I would love to have this functionality, but I put the code in my ~.bashrc~ and start a new shell - but it does not work for me.  Does it require a special Bash version?

Comment: @ChristianHerenz - Yes, I use `tmux` and this command works with its infrastructure

Answer (score 9):

you need to take a look at the bash `fc` command.

If you want to edit before rexecuting a history line just do like this

```
fc 123
```

where `123` is the history line number you see typing the command `history`.
It will open your favorite editor and allow you to modifiy the line then quit and save and it will run.

You can also do it a range of command like this:

```
fc 123 135
```

To work on command history from 123 to 135.

**Edit 1:**
if you need to run without edit consider watch the post [Re-execute fc command from history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114513/53092)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to reexecute a command from your history, you can use ^r (ctrl + r) in your terminal. It's a reverse search which permits to retrieve a command and edit it before you enter it. I don't know if it works with other shell than bash. Though it's like one of the most useful thing I ever seen.

From the bash documentation :

> reverse-search-history (C-r)
>   Search backward starting at the current line and moving ‘up’ through the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.

[Here is the manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html)

Comment: Yes that's also a possibility

Comment: It is useful if you want to execute only one command from your history. Your solution is better in case you want to execute multiple lines. Plus the ^r technique is useful because you don't actually have to know the line number in the history.

Comment: fc 'command begins… ' will find only the last line that started that way, invoke ***FCEDIT*** on the command, then run it.